# fail unit tests if coverage is below certain percentage

Tags: go, makefile

I make a makefile that executes `go test -cover`. Is it possible to fail the `make unit_tests` command if coverage is below X? How would I do that?

Comment: Not as part of the 'go test' tool, but it's possible to do that with an external command.

Comment: You can create your own test runner using the testing package, and it has a coverage function that you can call. https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Coverage

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `TestMain` in your test to do that. TestMain can act as a custom entry point to tests, and then you can invoke `testing.Coverage()` to get access to the coverage stats.

So for example, if you want to fail at anything below 80%, you could add this to one of your package's test files:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // call flag.Parse() here if TestMain uses flags
    rc := m.Run()

    // rc 0 means we've passed, 
    // and CoverMode will be non empty if run with -cover
    if rc == 0 && testing.CoverMode() != "" {
        c := testing.Coverage()
        if c < 0.8 {
            fmt.Println("Tests passed but coverage failed at", c)
            rc = -1
        }
    }
    os.Exit(rc)
}
```

Then `go test -cover` will call this entry point and you'll fail:

```
PASS
coverage: 63.0% of statements
Tests passed but coverage failed at 0.5862068965517241
exit status 255
FAIL    github.com/xxxx/xxx 0.026s
```

Notice that the number that `testing.Coverage()` returns is lower than what the test reports. I've looked at the code and the function calculates its coverage differently than the test's internal reporting. I'm not sure which is more "correct".

Comment: Awesome this works great on a package by package coverage basis. Is there way to get it to run tests all in packages so I don't have to copy TestMain() over to every package and set a coverage requirement on package basis.

Comment: It seems backwards to have to write more Go code in order to support this.  Between `go test -cover` and `go tool cover` you'd think there would be a simple way to get the total coverage percentage for a module from a shell.

Comment: @AlexJansen sounds like a great pull request to me :)

Comment: @Aman have you figured out how to measure coverage for all packages?