# Finding code coverage of a gRPC API based on API tests

Tags: go, continuous-integration, automated-tests, grpc, grpc-go

**Assumption**

- API tests are written in the same API code repository using GoLang
- API tests are run as part of the Pull Request CI build.
- An API test is basically starting gRPC server, making request from a golang based gRPC client and verifying the response

**Flow**

1. Dev starts building a new endpoint for an API
2. Dev does not write any API tests (please note that I mention specifically API tests and not unit tests)
3. Dev creates a Pull Request for the changes
4. The Pull Request should identify that there are no tests written for the new changes and block the PR

**My question**

How could we build a CI flow like this to achieve point 4?
I'm aware that code coverage is one way to go but I'm not fully convinced if that would be the correct approach for API tests?

Is it possible to find code coverage of gRPC service based on such API tests? If yes, then how?

Comment: Excuse me, but you have all bits and pieces of information you need, now it is time to think. Code coverage is a sufficient proof that tests are written, and writing tests for an API (be it the server or the client) does not work any different than any other server/client test, so does the coverage identification - you test the user provided functions, not the framework code.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Do you have any idea about how we can instrument a running instance of gRPC service to give code coverage?

Comment: A running instance? No, I have no idea. And I would not even know why, much less how.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Do you mean that it's not ideal to identify code coverage for such tests? If yes, why not? What's the philosophy behind not doing so? this is a discussion I'm also having with my peers and there's no conclusion.

Comment: There is no way to instrument a running instance for coverage. You simply write your code so that it can be tested with `go test`. For integration tests etc, you could use build tags. But unit tests and code coverage does not ensure tests. A PR in and of itself does not identify anything. What you'd usually do is a CI-build on PR and have it fail on coverage that is too small. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123125/1296707